# Notifications in Oreo not working if app is not running

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to show notifications in my app. All seems to be ok, but in Android 8.0 Oreo, if I kill the app the notification is not showed. In the previous versions of Android this is not a problem.

My source code is the next.

```
public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 600;
private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "bmedio_v6";         // This is the Notification Channel ID. More about this in the next section
private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "medio";             //User visible Channel Name
private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESC = "Medio Channel";             //User visible Channel Name

public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

public void showNotification(String title, String message) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESC);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    }else{
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    }

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_notify)
            //     .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message);

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

}

}
```

Comment: which mobile you use..??

Answer (score 0):

With the library of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm' 9.6.0 or higher the problem is solved. I was using GCM, not FCM.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, then I find the solution, you need to remove your app from **battery optimization list** mark your app **not optimize**, I did this in **onePlus5**, after killing an app also notification is working.

**step** :

1. goto **setting**
2. click on **Battery** option
3. click on **Battery optimization** , it will show list of app which is under optimation.
4. find your app select **don't optimize** and done!

just now I find out so now I need to see how to do this using code.
for mean while let me know if you faced the same issue or it will resolve your issue. :

Answer (score 0):

```
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),"channel_01")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setChannelId("channel_01")
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                    .setContentTitle(Title);

            mNotificationManager.notify(Notification_ID, mBuilder.build());

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(Notification_ID, "Playback Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            assert mNotificationManager != null;
            mBuilder.setChannelId("channel_01");
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        }else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),Notification_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(Title)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            mNotificationManager.notify(Notification_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Need to enable Auto Start in your mobile**

We cannot able to enable AutoStart directly. We should navigate to that screen

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
    } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
    } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
    }

    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if  (list.size() > 0) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
}
```